# Add error message on password protected page

Tags: forms, password

I protected a page with password. I’d like to add a short error message when the inserted password is incorrect.

How can I do this?

I add this code to show and customize the form on my page.

My `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'custom_password_form' );
function custom_password_form() {
global $post;
$label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
$o = '<form class="protected-post-form" action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-pass.php" method="post">' . 
'<p class="glossar-form-p">Alle weiteren Glossarbeiträge sind durch ein Passwort geschützt. </p>' . 
' <label for="' . $label . '">' . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Login" ) . '" />
</form>
';
return $o;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The latest entered password is stored as a secure hash in a cookie named `'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH`.

When the password form is called, that cookie has been **validated** already by WordPress. So you just have to check if that cookie **exists**: If it does and the password form is displayed, the password was wrong.

```
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg' );

/**
 * Add a message to the password form.
 *
 * @wp-hook the_password_form
 * @param   string $form
 * @return  string
 */
function wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg( $form )
{
    // No cookie, the user has not sent anything until now.
    if ( ! isset ( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] ) )
        return $form;

    // Translate and escape.
    $msg = esc_html__( 'Sorry, your password is wrong.', 'your_text_domain' );

    // We have a cookie, but it doesn’t match the password.
    $msg = "<p class='custom-password-message'>$msg</p>";

    return $msg . $form;
}
```

Comment: One issue I've found with this approach is that if you enter the wrong password the error message will persist even if you navigate away from the page and then come back, the simplest way I've found around this is to show the message only if `(wp_get_referer() == get_permalink())`

Comment: It works wonderful. How can I customize the typography color and alignment of the error message? Thanks

Comment: @CarolinaLallana in Your stylesheet, add a rule for the selector `.custom-password-message`, like this: `.custom-password-message { color: red; }`

Comment: I use above code. Its work well but error message not remove when we simple refresh page

Answer (score 4):

Following up from [fuxia](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/fuxia)'s answer. The complete snippet, including the check if the page load came from the same page, would be:

```
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg' );

/**
 * Add a message to the password form.
 *
 * @wp-hook the_password_form
 * @param   string $form
 * @return  string
 */
function wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg( $form )
{
    // No cookie, the user has not sent anything until now.
    if ( ! isset ( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] ) )
        return $form;

    // The refresh came from a different page, the user has not sent anything until now.
    if ( ! wp_get_raw_referer() == get_permalink() )
        return $form;

    // Translate and escape.
    $msg = esc_html__( 'Sorry, your password is wrong.', 'your_text_domain' );

    // We have a cookie, but it doesn’t match the password.
    $msg = "<p class='custom-password-message'>$msg</p>";

    return $msg . $form;
}
```

Just be sure to use `wp_get_raw_referer()` instead of `wp_get_referer()` as the latter will return `false` in case the current page and the referrer page are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's really really late to answer. Something you need to do the following. As there is no default way to validate you need to follow few steps. Here i gonna use session variable to check matching the generated cookies. first need to start session.

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');
function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Then use the following code where you want to show the error msg.

```
if ( post_password_required() ) {
       $session_id = 'wp-postpass_' . get_the_ID();
       //onload
       $current_cookie = wp_unslash($_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ]);
       //get old cookie 
       $old_cookie = isset( $_SESSION[ $session_id ] ) ? $_SESSION[ $session_id ] : '';
       //set new session
       $_SESSION[ $session_id ] = $current_cookie;
       if ( $current_cookie != $old_cookie && !empty( $old_cookie ) ){
           error_notification('<b>Error!</b> Authentication failed!');
       }
   }
```

That's it!!