# Add error message on password protected page ONLY when password introduced was incorrect

Tags: functions

I know this has been discussed in a couple of other posts but none of them seem to have the correct answer/solution to the question. I tried using all the suggested functions mentioned in the other posts but none seem to work. When a wrong password is introduced nothing happens(just the standard redirect to the same page)
The only one getting close to the answer is the following code provided by [toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho)  on this thread -  [Add error message on password protected page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71284/add-error-message-on-password-protected-page?rq=1) but unfortunately the error message shows regardless if the password was not introduced yet or as soon as you land on the page:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg' );
function wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg( $form )
{
// No cookie, the user has not sent anything until now.
if ( ! isset ( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] ) )
    return $form;

// Translate and escape.
$msg = esc_html__( 'Sorry, your password is wrong.', 'your_text_domain' );

// We have a cookie, but it doesn’t match the password.
$msg = "<p class='custom-password-message'>$msg</p>";

return $msg . $form;
}
?>
```

Your time and input is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you see the comment on Toscho's answer from that post? It might explain what you're seeing & provide a solution.

Comment: Hi @Michelle , the comment was saying they used `(wp_get_referer() == get_permalink())` to avoid the error message being displayed all the time but I am not sure where to introduce that code. Would you be able to advise?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg' );

/**
 * Add a message to the password form.
 *
 * @wp-hook the_password_form
 * @param   string $form
 * @return  string
 */
function wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg( $form )
{
    // No cookie, the user has not sent anything until now.
    if ( ! isset ( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] ) )
        return $form;

    // No cookie, person just submitted the form on this page and got the password wrong
    if (wp_get_referer() == get_permalink()) {
      // Translate and escape.
      $msg = esc_html__( 'Sorry, your password is wrong.', 'your_text_domain' );

      // We have a cookie, but it doesn’t match the password.
      $msg = "<p class='custom-password-message'>$msg</p>";
    } else {
      $msg = "";
    }
    return $msg . $form;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @Michelle but unfortunately the password form does not appear anymore on my pages when I insert your code in my functions.php. Any idea what may cause this?

Comment: Hmm.... added an 'else' statement and moved the form return, try that. (See edited code).

Comment: The form appears but no error message appears when password is wrong, sorry. Can't understand why...

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

for me, this code works:

```
function my_password_form() {
     global $post;

     $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );

     $passwordProtectedPageURL = get_the_permalink();
     $wrongPassword = ' ';

     if( ( sanitize_text_field( $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ) === $passwordProtectedPageURL ) &&  isset ( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] )){
          $wrongPassword = '<span style="color:#ed1b24;font-weight:bold;">Contraseña incorrecta, por favor inténtalo de nuevo.</span>';
          setcookie ('wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, null, -1);

     }


     $form = '<form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post" class="post-password-form">
' . "<p>Este contenido está protegido por contraseña. Para verlo, por favor, introduce tu contraseña a continuación:</p>" . '
<p><label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' <input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /></label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" /></p>
</form><p>' . $wrongPassword . '</p>';

     return $form;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );
```

The messages are in spanish, but they are easy to change.